# Wood behind drywall near water shut off

Tags: drywall, wood, structural

Some time in-between our inspection and closing, some idiot decided to drywall over the water shut off. Annoying, but I thought I'd just cut a hole and install an access panel. Only problem is, when I started to cut the drywall, I noticed whoever did the drywall seems to have put wood there. It's not very thick, or very wide so I've managed to get to the shut off valve, but it's quite hard to stick my hand in there to shut it off all the way. Is there anyway to know if this wood is safe to cut through, to bring the hole back to an accessible [image: Wood in question]size?

Comment: The wood is probably just an aid to hold a drywall patch in place for mudding. How much drywall was installed?

Comment: That's what I figured. I'm not sure on how much, the original hole wasn't very large, but we had the seller fix some plumbing issues, not sure if they made it bigger for some reason before patching up the whole thing. If it's just for mudding, it's good to saw through?

Comment: Get a cheap borescope and take a better look inside to see how the wood is attach to anything else behind the drywall.  But I agree—odds are it's just a backer for the drywall patch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was just to hold a drywall patch in position for mudding. Just cut it as needed. After you get your access cut in, you can confirm that it was just for a patch by feeling around for the edges of the patch where mud squeezed through to the back of the drywall. Just be careful not to stab yourself with drywall screws sticking out the back of the board.